# Drive letter keeps changing on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, backup, windows-server-2012-r2, drive-letter

We require to take backup for client regularly on L drive.We assigned the drive letter 'L' from disk management but when the next tape is inserted for next day backup it goes back to H again. We keep changing the drive letter to 'L' but drive letter automatically becomes H every time a new tape is inserted.

Didn't know how to fix it so we rebooted the server but that didn't do any good.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In this order:

1. Insert tape and mount the file system
2. Next, make sure the drive's system restore option is disabled for this drive.
3. Then, regedit then search for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices and rename the corresponding /DosDevice/H: entry to /DosDevice/L:

Windows system restore will reserve the hardware the drive letter, Disabling it on the drive will cause the system to read the /DosDevice entry. With some group policy option settings, you must disable system restore on the whole system, then reserve the drive letter in disk management.

Comment: How do I disable the drive's system restore option?

Comment: in windows 2012 server they call it windows server backup. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770757.aspx